# python string parsing doesn't parse newline character

Tags: python, xml, string, parsing, minidom

In python I am trying to read the string from the xml tag using minidom . But the parsed string's newline characters can't be detected. Here is the xml tag that I am trying to parse :

```
<Command>setlocal
C:\t\gfx\CMake2.8\bin\cmake.exe --check-stamp-file "C:\Source\Workspace\generate.stamp"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal &amp; call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% &amp; goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd</Command>
```

My minidom parsing code is :

```
nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName("Command")
for j in range(len(nodes)):
  path = nodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue
  if path.find('\n') : 
    print '\n found'
```

but this doesn't work, in spite of the string having '\n' characters at the end of "setlocal", ":cmEnd", ":cmErrorLevel" etc.
I also tried to encode the input string :

```
path = path.encode('utf-8')
```

and then run the above code, but that doesn't work too. 
I have also tried to `find('\\n')` but doesn't work.

Does anyone have solution to my problem ?

Comment: try `if '\n' in path:` instead of `if path.find('\n')`, `.find` will give the newline's place in the string, not a boolean if it exists. Also have you tried printing `path` to make sure the blob that you expect to search is being parsed correctly?

Comment: @CasualDemon : yes the blob that I expect to search is being parsed correctly. The problem is that this string doesn't explicitely contain '\n' character. `if '\n' in path:` doesn't work too.

Comment: My guess is the blob contains carriage return + linefeed (Windows line ending).

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this as I was looking for a solution to a similar problem.

I copied and pasted your xml into a doc and saved it as an xml file.

Then I did this

```
>>> xml = ('command.xml')
>>> xml_file = open(xml).read()
>>> xml_file 
'<Command>setlocal\nC:\\t\\gfx\\CMake2.8\\bin\\cmake.exe --check-stamp-file  "C:\\Source\\Workspace\\generate.stamp"\nif %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd\n:cmEnd\nendlocal &amp; call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% &amp; goto :cmDone\n:cmErrorLevel\nexit /b %1\n:cmDone\nif %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd</Command>'
>>> if '\n' in xml_file:
...     print '\\n found'
... 
\n found
>>> xml_file.count('\n')
8
```

Is this sort of what you were looking for? If you already solved it, then what solution did you use?